# cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why am I getting this error? Tried running Passenger stand-alone on Ubuntu 20.04 server nothing fancy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by ensuring that I started passenger in production mode.

```
cd /home/kiffin/server-name/production/current
passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d --user kiffin --daemonize --environment production
```